# Allure error after updating SpecFlow package

Tags: c#, specflow, allure

I am writing tests using Specflow, C#, and Allure to generate reports. After updating packages

- Specflow,
- Specflow.xUnit
- SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation

from version **3.3.57** to **3.4.31**
I get this error:

```
System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Allure.SpecFlowPlugin.AllureTestTracerWrapper' threw an exception.
---- System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Allure.SpecFlowPlugin.PluginHelper' threw an exception.
-------- System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 'Void TechTalk.SpecFlow.FeatureInfo..ctor(System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.String, System.String, System.String[])'
```

Do you know how can I resolve this issues?

Thank you for any advice or suggestions on how to solve this issue.

[image: Exception details]

Comment: Did you do a clean build of all projects to remove all the intermediate obj files?

Comment: Yes, it does not help

Comment: There is a new manual that came out today that may help. Look for exception.  See : https://docs.specflow.org/_/downloads/specflow/en/latest/pdf/

Comment: See para 2.3 of link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specflow.Allure package is now updated to support SpecFlow 3.4+
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.Allure/3.5.0.4

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this error is that SpecFlow.Allure does not yet work together with SpecFlow 3.4. The dependency on the NuGet package with >=3.3.57 is wrong.

We made changes in SpecFlow to 3.4 that are not compatible with 3.3.

The GitHub Issue for this is here: https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-csharp/issues/133

As long as Allure doesn't update the NuGet package, you have to go back to SpecFlow 3.3.